# ADO - MySQL - SHOW BINLOG EVENTS

Tags: mysql, ado, recordset

Any one who can explain this, perhaps another solution.....

The software is W2019 and MySQL 8.0.18...

When I run this query in ASP Classic and ADO

```
Result.Open "SHOW BINLOG EVENTS LIMIT 0,10",MySQLConn
```

or

```
Set Result = MySQLConn.Execute("SHOW BINLOG EVENTS LIMIT 0,10")
```

I get this result:

```
Log_name        Pos     Event_type      Server_id       End_log_pos     Info     
W2019_SERVER-bin.000        4       Format_desc     1       124     Server ver: 8.0.18,      
W2019_SERVER-bin.000        124     Previous_gtids      1       155          
W2019_SERVER-bin.000        155     Anonymous_Gtid      1       234     SET @@SESSION.GTID_N     
W2019_SERVER-bin.000        234     Query       1       319     BEGIN    
W2019_SERVER-bin.000        319     Table_map       1       415     table_id: 101 (hmail     
W2019_SERVER-bin.000        415     Update_rows     1       769     table_id: 101 flags:     
W2019_SERVER-bin.000        769     Xid     1       800     COMMIT /* xid=43 */  
W2019_SERVER-bin.000        800     Anonymous_Gtid      1       879     SET @@SESSION.GTID_N     
W2019_SERVER-bin.000        879     Query       1       972     BEGIN    
W2019_SERVER-bin.000        972     Table_map       1       1068        table_id: 101 (hmail
```

Expected is this (from phpMyAdmin):

```
Log_name    Pos     Event_type  Server_id   End_log_pos     Info    
W2019_SERVER-bin.000019     4   Format_desc     1   124     Server ver: 8.0.18, Binlog ver: 4
W2019_SERVER-bin.000019     124     Previous_gtids  1   155     
W2019_SERVER-bin.000019     155     Anonymous_Gtid  1   234     SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'ANONYMOUS'
W2019_SERVER-bin.000019     234     Query   1   319     BEGIN
W2019_SERVER-bin.000019     319     Table_map   1   415     table_id: 101 (hmail.hm_fetchaccounts)
W2019_SERVER-bin.000019     415     Update_rows     1   769     table_id: 101 flags: STMT_END_F
W2019_SERVER-bin.000019     769     Xid     1   800     COMMIT /* xid=43 */
W2019_SERVER-bin.000019     800     Anonymous_Gtid  1   879     SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'ANONYMOUS'
W2019_SERVER-bin.000019     879     Query   1   972     BEGIN
W2019_SERVER-bin.000019     972     Table_map   1   1068    table_id: 101 (hmail.hm_fetchaccounts)
```

It seems like ADO is cutting my recordsets at the wrong place (first and last columns)

Any one with any idea(s) ? :D